# Дамп файлов БД во время тестирования или очень медленные тесты

Tags: mysql, yii2, vagrant, codeception

У меня есть проект на PHP с использованием Yii2 и тестирую я все это дело Codeception.

Все бы ничего, но тесты с использованием БД выполняются **нереально долго**. В частности, по причине большого количества фикстур с большим количеством данных.

Я даже разделил тесты на unit и integration -- с без БД и с ним.
Посмотрите на разницу:

```
$ time ./vendor/bin/codecept run unit
Tests.unit Tests (67) 
Time: 4.22 seconds, Memory: 71.25MB

OK (67 tests, 380 assertions)

real    0m6.044s
user    0m1.292s
sys     0m0.208s
```

Интеграционные:

```
$ time ./vendor/bin/codecept run integration
Tests.integration Tests (35) 
Time: 4.76 minutes, Memory: 54.25MB
Tests: 35, Assertions: 58, Failures: 1.

real    4m46.052s
user    4m35.880s
sys     0m0.584s
```

То есть где-то в 50 раз дольше.

Вопрос вот в чем: вместо того, чтобы загружать и выгружать из БД строки, может быть можно как-то выгрузить в БД все данные, сохранить файл таблицы со всеми этими данными и перед каждым тестом копировать этот файл, восстанавливая набор тестовых данных. В SQLite с этим проще, но в моем случае подменить не получится.

Если это не возможно или не имеет смысла, то как я могу ускорить выполнение тестов с использованием БД?

Дополнительная информация:

- Я использую [официальный метод загрузки фикстур в Yii2 через метод _fixtures](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Yii2#fixtures)
- Данных в фикстурах может быть много и обычно они все нужны для сохранения целостности и эмуляции боевых условий.
- БД для тестов лежит внутри vagrant окружения. Возможно, проблема кроется именно в этом. Но я бы не хотел выносить БД из гостевой системы в хост. Выполнение тестов внутри Vagrant машины не дает никакого прироста.
- Возможно кто-то посоветует Docker, но не получается у меня как-то с ним. Может быть нужна практика, но пока что у меня с ним даже не на "Вы", а на "Оно"
- Используемая БД -- MySQL
- Моки -- это круто. До тех пор, пока они актуальны. Но проблема в том, что в этом случае очень важно, чтобы **все вместе** работало хорошо, а не только отдельный модуль. К тому же нельзя отрицать, что создание большого количества моков делает тесты практически нечитабельными.

Answer (score 2):

Для тех кто наткнется на ту же проблему, отпишу здесь.

**1)** **Пожалуйста, следите за версиями Mysql** и их обновлениями, даже на пару версий "Состарившаяся" база данных может очень сильно влиять на загрузку и отладку кода.

**2)** **Главное правило скорости работы систем** Избегать любых возможных "посредников" программ в вашем коде, чем их больше, тем по умолчанию код исполняется дольше. Будьте параноидальны во включении сторонних скриптов и сред которые "якобы" я подчеркну "якобы" упрощают вам жизнь, относитесь к ним как к ступеням лестницы из соломы, при этом вы стоите на ней на высоте 50 этажа. Рано или поздно эта "надежда" из посредников вас подведет. Чем больше посредников - тем ниже скорость работы системы и тем более она подвержена взлому. В вашем примере вопроса, их как минимум 3 насчитал.

**3)**  **vagrant**  окружение и скорость работы через него также зависит от способа использования. Как именно подключались вы - вопрос.

**4) Ну и конечно королевский вопрос.** Что именно  вы подразумеваете под "тестом" ?  Описывайте максимально конкретно результаты, которые вы хотите получить от системы, в том числе задавая вопросы на So.

Спасибо за внимание.